# Fixing Grammar Errors in rosws Tutorial

Tags: ros, rosws, tutorial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [rosws tutorial](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/rosinstall/html/rosws_tutorial.html) has several grammar errors.  For example in the second sentence "In you get stuck" should be "In case you get stuck".

Where do I report these errors or how can I volunteer to fix them?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39323/fixing-grammar-errors-in-rosws-tutorial/) by [liangfok](https://answers.ros.org/users/1811/liangfok/) on ROS Answers with karma: 328 on 2012-07-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the best way is to file a ticket at the corresponding [trac](https://kforge.ros.org/vcstools/trac).

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The documentation is maintained in the source code, so you can download the source code:

```
$  https://kforge.ros.org/vcstools/rosinstall
```

then make the changes in the doc subfolder. You can then create a patch to attch to your tieckt (see Lorenz' answer) like this:

```
$ hg diff doc
```

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-07-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4